Assignments of people to urinals
The following problem arrived to me in a dream:

Austin, Eric, Jeff, and Michael are standing in front of a line of ten urinals. An assignment of people to urinals is called good if:

each urinal has at most two people assigned to it, and
no two people are assigned to adjacent urinals.

Compute the number of good assignments.

I’ve tried casework, but there seems to be many cases if the number of people is large. I’m not sure if there’s a clean solution without lots of computation. Any help would be greatly appreciated. In particular, I’m interested in closed-form solutions where each urinal has at most $m$ people assigned to it.

Why even in a dream would you assign two people to an urinal when there are excess urinals ?

and more so, if two users at one urinal is accepted, how come two users at two adjacent urinals isn't?

@trueblueanil to cross the streams, obviously

Interesting dreams you're having...
We take cases on the "doubled" urinals (i.e. those with 2 people).
Case 1: No urinals are doubled. There are $24$ ways to sort the people. Now the problem becomes finding numbers $a,b,c,d$ corresponding to the urinals such that $1\leq a<b<c<d\leq 10$, where the differences are at least $2$. This is equivalent to the condition $1\leq a<b-1<c-2<d-3\leq 7$, which has $\binom{7}{4}=35$ ways of selection. The total is therefore $35\cdot 24=840$.
Case 2: One urinal is doubled. There are $\binom{4}{2}=6$ ways to choose a pair of people to double and $6$ ways of arrangement. Using the same method as the first case, we want $1\leq a<b-1<c-2\leq 8$, with $\binom 83=56$ ways of selection. The total is $56\cdot 6\cdot 6=2016$.
Case 3: Two urinals are doubled. There are $\binom 42=6$ ways for doubling and arrangement. We want $1\leq a<b-1\leq 9$, which has $\binom{9}{2}=36$ ways of selection. That's a total of $36\cdot 6=216$.
The grand total is therefore $840+2016+216=3072$ ways.

In general, for an even number of people $k$ and $n$ urinals, the formula is
$$\sum_{i=0}^{\frac k2}\binom{k}{2i}\frac{(2i)!}{2^ii!}(k-i)!\binom{n-k+i+1}{k-i}.$$

Thanks! Do you know if there’s a general formula where each urinal has at most $m$ people assigned to it?

@PunySoloist For larger $m$, there's probably a way to do it, but the same method used here won't apply since there'll be many more cases for how the different "groupings" on each urinal would look like.

Here's a generating function approach for the general case of "at most $m$ assigned to one urinal".
Let the variable $x$ record the number of urinals and $y$ the number of people. We take the generating function $G(x,y)$ to be ordinary in the variable $x$ and exponential in the variable $y$.
By considering the first urinal that is occupied (if such exists) we get the equation
$$
G = \frac{1}{1-x} + \frac{1}{1-x}x\left(y+ \frac{1}{2!}y^2+\dots+ \frac{1}{m!}y^m \right)(1+xG)
$$
Explanation: Either we have a sequence of empty urinals ($\frac{1}{1-x}$) or after a sequence of empties ($\frac{1}{1-x}$) there is an occupied (by up to $m$ people) urinal ($x\left(y+ \frac{1}{2!}y^2+\dots+ \frac{1}{m!}y^m \right)$) and that is followed by nothing or by an empty urinal followed by a similar construction ($1+xG$).
This gives
$$
G = \frac{1+ x\left(y+ \frac{1}{2!}y^2+\dots+ \frac{1}{m!}y^m \right) }{1-x-x^2 \left(y+ \frac{1}{2!}y^2+\dots+ \frac{1}{m!}y^m \right) }.
$$
We can write (denoting $h = y+ \frac{1}{2!}y^2+\dots+ \frac{1}{m!}y^m $)
$$
xG+1 = \frac{1}{1-x-x^2h}
= \sum_{a=0}^\infty (x+x^2h)^a
= \sum_{a=0}^\infty \sum_{b=0}^a \binom{a}{b} x^{a-b+2b}h^b
$$
Here we used formula for geometric series and binomial theorem.
Extracting the coefficient of $x^{n+1}$ (since this is $xG+1$ so for $n>0$ it gives $[x^n]G$) yields
$$\large
\sum_{a= \left \lceil \frac{n+1}{2} \right\rceil}^{n+1} \binom{a}{n+1-a}h^{n+1-a}
= \sum_{j=0}^{ \left \lfloor \frac{n+1}{2} \right\rfloor} \binom{n+1-j}{j}h^j.
$$
Then expanding $h^j$ will give $m-1$ additional sums and extracting $k![y^k]$ kills one of them so there will be $m-1$ sums in the answer.
For $m=2$ we get (I think this is equivalent to CosmicOscillator's formula after some shuffling of terms)
$$ {\large 
\frac{k!}{2^k} \sum_{j=\left \lfloor \frac{k}{2} \right\rfloor}^{\left \lceil \frac{n+1}{2} \right\rceil} } \binom{n+1-j}{j} \binom{j}{2j-k}2^j
$$
and for $m=3$
$$ {\large
\frac{k!}{2^k} \sum_{a=0}^{\left \lceil \frac{n+1}{2} \right\rceil} \sum_{b=\max(0,\frac{k}{2}-a)}^a}
\binom{n+1-a}{a}\binom{a}{k-a-2b}\binom{2(a+b)-k}{b}2^{a+2b}6^{-b}
$$
